# ¿Cómo puedo tomar las propiedades **name** de un formulario en php?

Tags: php, ajax, json

Tengo un problema no se como tomar las propiedades **name** de un formulario en PHP, es una aplicación web para crear rubricas, el número de **campos** va a depender del numero de descriptores y indicadores elegidos por el usuario mas el campo donde se especificara el nivel de dominio, es decir si el usuario elige que la rubrica va a tener 2 niveles de dominio y cada nivel tendrá 5 indicadores por 4 descriptores esto sera igual a 5 indicadores y 20 descriptores más el campo donde se describirá el nivel de dominio, estoy utilizando *ajax* para mandar los datos tomados por cada propiedad *name* del formulario, en ese aspecto no hay problema, pero cundo voy al **script de php** no se como tomar esas propiedades *name*, lo que yo hice fue crear un arreglo en php  con todo los nombres de las propiedades name del formulario, pero el problema esta en que no puedo rescatar las propiedades name que me se mando por ajax y compararlas con las del arreglo, de esta manera solo tomaría los valores con $_POST["descript1"] para almacenar en la bd, alguna sugerencia... necesito ayuda. [image: Lo rojo son los descriptores, los ND son los niveles de dominio y los IND son los indicadores]

Comment: Ramón bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Para futuras preguntas, considera usar el punto y aparte, así tu planteamiento quedará más claro y entendible :). En cuanto a la pregunta, hay diversas formas de hacerlo. Si quisieras todo el formulario, con un simple `serialize`, lo guardarías por completo en una variable para pasarlo al servidor. Como quieres sólo una parte de él, entonces, puedes identificar esas partes del formulario que quieres con la misma clase por ejemplo y luego recuperar los elementos en base a esa clase. Así no tienes que hacerlo *a mano*, uno por uno.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ejemplo(e){
   e.preventdefault();
   var nombre = $("[name="nombre"]").val(); 
   var edad = $("[name="edad"]").val();
   // aqui creo el json.
   var json = {
     nom:nombre,
     ed:edad
   }
   //aqui creo el ajax
   $.ajax({
     type:'POST',
     data:json,
     url:'ejemplo.php',

   })

}


//aqui es donde creo el php con los datos q llegan del json


$nombre = $_POST['nom'];
$edad = $_POST['ed'];
```

espero esto te pueda servir

Answer (score 0):

Podrías agrupar en un contenedor las partes del formulario que quieres enviar, por ejemplo un `div`. Sería la mejor opción si todos los elementos estuvieran una después del otro.

Si no, puedes identificarlos con un nombre de clase común.

Una vez indentificados, puedes usar `serialize`, para agrupar todos los elementos contenidos en ese rango.

---

### Agrupados por bloques contiguos mediante el id del contenedor

En este ejemplo, se enviarán los `input` del `Bloque1` o del `Bloque2`, según el botón que pulses.

```js
$(function() {

    $('#btnBloque1').on('click', function() {
        alert($('#divBloque1 input').serialize());
    });

      $('#btnBloque2').on('click', function() {
        alert($('#divBloque2 input').serialize());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id='myForm' method='post'>
    <div id='divBloque1'>
        <input name='ibxNombe' type='text' placeholder='Escriba Nombre'>
        <input name='ibxApelido' type='text' placeholder='Escriba Apellido'>
        <button id='btnBloque1'>Enviar bloque 1</button>
    </div>
    <div id='divBloque2'>
        <input name='ibxEmpresa' type='text' placeholder='Escriba Empresa'>
        <input name='ibxCiudad' type='text' placeholder='Escriba Ciudad'>
        <button id='btnBloque2'>Enviar bloque 2</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

---

### Agrupados por Clase

Aquí, agrupamos por las clases `clsBloque1` y `clsBloque2`. Podrás observar que hay elementos personales, luego los de la empresa y luego otros personales, del padre y de la madre. No obstante, los elementos personales se enviarán juntos, porque se agrupa por la clase.

```js
    $(function() {

        $('#btnBloque1').on('click', function() {
            alert($('.clsBloque1 input').serialize());
        });

          $('#btnBloque2').on('click', function() {
            alert($('.clsBloque2 input').serialize());
        });
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <form id='myForm' method='post'>
        <div class='clsBloque1'>
            <input name='ibxNombe' type='text' placeholder='Escriba Nombre'>
            <input name='ibxApelido' type='text' placeholder='Escriba Apellido'>
        </div>
        <div clas='clsBloque2'>
            <input name='ibxEmpresa' type='text' placeholder='Escriba Empresa'>
            <input name='ibxCiudad' type='text' placeholder='Escriba Ciudad'>
            <button id='btnBloque2'>Enviar bloque 2</button>
        </div>

        <div class='clsBloque1'>
            <input name='ibxPadre' type='text' placeholder='Escriba Nombre del Padre'>
            <input name='ibxMadre' type='text' placeholder='Escriba Nombre de la Madre'>
            <button id='btnBloque1'>Enviar bloque 1</button>

            </div>
</form>
```